# Outlook 2016 does not receive mail unless outlook restarted

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2016

**Issue:**

I have user whose Outlook 2016 does not update new mails. mails are received only after restarting outlook.

What I have tried:

- Recreating profile.
- Opening outlook in safemode
- Manual send/receive
- Reset navpane
- Turned off addin like vba, symantec, outlook social connect.
- Work offline if off.

Wifi speed is good 5 GHZ. Clients connects from a VPN. Download speed 20 MBps. i'm now out of ideas. OWA receives mail properly.

Comment: My hunch would be that client is on a mobile hotspot and that outlook detects mobile data and refuses to send/receive.

Comment: Check Outlook Send/Receive settings to ensure set up properly.

Comment: the client is now on Office ethernet connection. same problem.

Comment: send/receive is not updating the mailbox. i have recreated the profile again. no changes. Also just tried re-installing Office. This is a new laptop Dell latitude 7320.

Answer (score 0):

What is the detailed version of outlook are you using(**File > Office Account > About Outlook**)? Please make sure that you have upgrade it to the latest version.

- How do you re-create a profile? From control Panel? If not, it is recommended you create a new profile follow the steps:
  Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > Add
- Is it an Exchange account? If so, check your account setting follow the steps:

1. Go to File > Account settings > Account Settings > Change
2. Open up **More Settings**
3. Then go to the Advanced tab and uncheck **Download shared folder** under the Cached Exchange Mode Settings.

[image]

Hope this can help you!

Comment: HI Thank you for the repy. It is an Exchange account. I reconfigured the outlook account from control panel -> mail -> show profile -> Add. 
the dowload shared folder is unchecked by default.

Comment: What about performing a clean boot? you can refer to this article:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd

Comment: Hi, The mailbox is very huge - 15GB. So i'm thinking the mailbox needs to update all the mail in inbox. The user is bringing the laptop to office to leave it overnight on office network. Hope this will solve the problem.